# Clean install of 15.10 (32 bit) gives cursor only blank screen after login

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Please can someone help. I am trying to install ubuntu onto a Wiped Vaio.
The install seems top work perfectly, formating the hard drive and installing updates (including 3rd party). The problemis only evident after login when the screen goes blank and only a flashing cursor is visible. I can get to a bash screen but after trying many different 'solutions' mentioned in these forums I still cannot get the screen to work properly.
I am convinced the problem is with the nvidia driver and apologise in advance if the answer is already out there, but I am slowly losing the will to ubuntu!

Sony Vaio VGC-V2S - PCV-E11M with nVidia GeForce FX Go5700

I am just going to reinstall from scratch to remove any residues of all my previous failed attempts to fix this problem.

Thank you in advance, please go easy on me as I am an Ubuntu novice,

Comment: I have just tried another clean install and followed the advice in 'My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?' using both the PPA Way or the Default Ubuntu way. Both give the same result - when entering login details and pressing return loops back to login screen.

Comment: For anyone reading the above, thinking you have the same problem?

Comment: PLEASE follow my advice and save yourself a lot of trouble - FORGET trying to install Ubuntu - install the equivalent version of XUBUNTU. Worked first time and has the same capabilities. The only real difference I am aware of is the desktop enviroment (screen layout), which is just as easy to use! I wish I had installed it first, it literally would have saved me 30+ hrs of my life and a lot of headaches!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**escapologist**, like yourself I've been "banging my head against a brick wall" trying to solve/fix/workaround the Ubuntu nVIDIA GPU problems.

So thanks for your solution, I've installed XUbuntu 14.04 and have not experienced ANY of the nVIDIA problems that are plaguing Ubuntu. Strange that both use the same NVIDIA drivers !!!

If anyone tries the Ubuntu Live Session distro then check for video corruption when using DASH. If you see any then XUbuntu is the answer